# Access object in main from other class

Tags: java

In my main class I have `public static Pet myPet = new Pet();`.
I have another class "Welcome" from which I want to access myPet. I want this object to be used in my whole project (it's a game, swing, and this pet will be the main character). I can use `Main.myPet.setName();` but I don't know if it's good practice. This just seems the most natural to me. I don't know if starting new windows and passing it as a parameter is a good solution. Is there any other way to access this object or it'll be fine to leave it like that?

Comment: This is a so-called `singleton`.  You may want to read up on the concept to understand what implications this may have on your application.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen no, this is not an example of singleton. It's just a single instance, but not a singleton (then the instance of Pet would be in a private static field of Pet).

Comment: Close enough for now (and the `final` keyword would be sufficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is ever going to be only one "pet" instance, and you don't intend to implement things like game saving, I see no harm in it.

Static fields may sometimes be considered a code smell (bad practice), but if the application is really simple, it's not a problem and can help readability.

If you plan to add game saving etc, it may be a good idea to have a class representing the game state, and the pet being it's field. Then pass *this* around, not the pet itself - you may later add more things to the game, and you just add them to the game state class.

Answer (score 1):

If your object is only going to be used inside of your main method instantiate it as `Pet myPet = new Pet();`

If you are going to use the object over several methods in your main class declare it as `private static Pet myPet = new Pet();`

However, I advise you to refrain from instantiating the object as a static instance of a class because it will not allow you to test properly.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using static variables like this, as this will limit what you can do with the code, including how you can expand it or test it (such as with unit testing). Instead, try to keep most all of your code out of the static world and in the instance world. The main method should mainly be used for setting the actors in position and then starting them up, and little else. Pass references where needed if you need classes to share objects. Most important, and I can't stress this enough, get a good book, or several books, on object-oriented programming principles and study it.

Comment: Agreed.  New Java programmers should avoid using the `static` keyword except when defining the main-function.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do it by creating accessors/ mutators( get and set methods) in order not to expose all members to every other object. Therefore pet must be private, or a static variable inside a utility class, also via get and set accessible. Unless there is no real reason for making a member public, avoid it whenever possible. This ensures encapsulation and is a best practice oo Design rule.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider changing your class definition of `Pet` to the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), rather than defining it as a static field in your main class. For example:

```
public class Pet {
    private static volatile Pet instance = null;
    //other fields for Pet

    //Private constructor to prevent instantiation without calling getInstance
    private Pet() { }
    //getInstance ensures that only a single instance of the Pet class is instantiated
    public static Pet getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Pet.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Pet();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
    //other methods for Pet
}
```

You could then use this in your main class, or any other class, by using the following line:

```
Pet myPet = Pet.getInstance();
```

Calling the static method getInstance for the first time will create a new `Pet` object, but every time it is called after that it will return the same instance of `Pet`, essentially creating a globally accessible instance of `Pet`. However, you should read up on the benefits and drawbacks of using a singleton pattern before using it. The singleton pattern is generally frowned upon, but it can be useful in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the welcome class to access the information from your previous class. public class Welcome extends PetmyPet {.